# Ant Build Script Java Config Web project

Tags: java, spring, maven, ant

I am using spring 4 in my dynamic web project which is fully annotation based java config (there is no web.xml). When I try to package with my ant build. It's giving error webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml does not exist.

My build script is like bellow:

```
 <war destfile="${maven.build.dir}/${maven.build.finalName}.war" 
         compress="true" 
         needxmlfile="false" 
         >
      ......
      ......
    </war>
```

What is the way to solve this error?

Comment: Why ant? Looks like you are slapping ant onto a maven project? Why make it extra complex?

Comment: We want to build maven project by Ant to auto deploy using Deploy Plugin - Jenkins.

Comment: Why? Jenkins is perfectly capable of do that with maven only, no need to add another layer of complexity...

Answer (score 0):

Add 'needxmlfile' attribute and set it to false.

For further reference [Ant War Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but please have a look another one time that is already in my code.

Comment: What is the version of dynamic web module, hope it is greater than 2.5?

Comment: I tried creating simple dynamic web project. It first gave me same error which you're getting and then I added needxmlfile='false'  in build.xml and it worked fine for me.